# class not found when using Hadoop Streaming and New API File format

Tags: java, python, hadoop, streaming

When using a Hadoop python streaming with NEW API and Custom (java) out format or (java) Reducer Class not found problem occurs. Whereas the same works fine with OLD API.

i.e. 
following command line arguments work file with old api but has problems with new api.

```
   -inputformat JavaClassName
   -outputformat JavaClassName
   -partitioner JavaClassName
   -combiner streamingCommand or JavaClassNam
```

example If you check out this blog post: http://research.neustar.biz/2011/08/30/custom-inputoutput-formats-in-hadoop-streaming/ if you try to implement this with new MultipleOutputs (reducer) i had problems with local Hadoop and AWS EMR.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like -libjars option is missing. Specify the jar, which contains the custom format and custom partitioner along with -libjars option also set the newly created jar in the environment variable HADOOP_CLASSPATH as follows before executing hadoop command

`export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}:Path-Custom-Format.jar`

Answer (score 0):

True, see http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-11959

While using hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar, I faced the same difficulty for customized partitioner class. I got it working by

1. importing org.apache.hadoop.mapred packages instead of respective mapreduce packages.
2. implementing Partitioner interface, instead of extending Partitioner class

Guess, that's same as older api.